# Mejorar mi widget card flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hola tengo el siguiente codigo para hacer un card, quisiera saber si se puede mejorar con respecto a lo que hice. Este es el codigo de mi card.

```
 return Card(
  elevation: 5,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 65,
          child: ListTile(
            trailing: Card(
              elevation: 4,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
              child: ClipOval(
                child: Material(
                  color: Colors.grey[50], // button color
                  child: InkWell(
                    child: SizedBox(
                        width: 40,
                        height: 40,
                        child: SizedBox(
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: Image.asset(
                              'data/assets/compass.png',
                              height: 20,
                              width: 20,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () => (0),
                          ),
                        )),
                    onTap: () {},
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            title: Text(
              'Esto es un titulo',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            subtitle: Text('Av. Argentina 365, Lima'),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
          child: Text('Tiempo transcurrido, 00:00:35:20'),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
          child: Divider(
            thickness: 1.4,
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0, bottom: 16.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.car_rental),
              Text('Willy / CDA-123'),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Este es lo que quiero lograr, hago la pregunta porque he estado utilizando mucho el width y heigh. he intentado ver la forma que se pueda reducir el codigo.
Como use ClipOval quise colocar elevation pero para eso tuve que crear un card y colocarlo ahi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy nuevo en Flutter,gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Debido que el componente es complejo, lo recomendable sería dividirlo en widgets pequeños. Crea clases para separar sus componentes internos y asi seguir su edición.

```dart
return Card(
    elevation: 5,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),),
    child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
            children: [
                _CardHeader(),
                Divider(thickness: 1.4,),
                _CardFooter(),
            ],
           ),
          ),
         );
```

```dart
class _CardHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Esto es un titulo',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
              child: Text('Av. Argentina 365, Lima'),
            ),
            RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                text: 'Tiempo transcurrido,',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                children: [
                  TextSpan(
                    text: ' 00:00:35:20',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Material(
          child: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(Icons.near_me),
          ),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          ),
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
          elevation: 5,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
class _CardFooter extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Icon(Icons.directions_car),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
          child: Text('Willy / CDA-123'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

El problema con usar medidas en tus widgets esque se pierda el responsive en algunos dispositivos, lo más recomendable es usar los widgets `material` o `cupertino`.